# Show json in render and parse user input in onChange of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to display bunch of json object using map within a textarea. User can edit it, but I have to validate all the json is valid before it got passed to the backend.

I'm having problem parsing it, where should I parse it? Parse JSON within the onChange doesn't sounds like a good idea, it break if user input is not valid json.

```
onChange = (e, idx) => {
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data.map((o,i) => {
        if(i === idx){
          return JSON.parse(e.target.value) //dangerous
        }
        return o
      })
    })
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/880414y0m0

Comment: Took a look at your sandbox, there are a lot more issues that need to be resolved aside from this

Comment: @EddieDelRio those are just warning.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed It 2.0**
You should't parse until submission. Otherwise it'll break whenever you start typing. Because at some point, the text will not be valid JSON. As soon as I type `{`, if I try to parse that, than it would break. Re-wrote. Lemme know if there's any more bugs

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: [""]
    };
    this.getAllStates = this.getAllStates.bind(this);
    this.addField = this.addField.bind(this);
    this.removeField = this.removeField.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e, ind) {
    let state = { ...this.state };
    let { value } = e.target;
    state.data[ind] = value;

    this.setState(state);
  }

  addField(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let state = { ...this.state };
    state.data.push("");
    this.setState(state);
  }

  removeField(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let state = { ...this.state };
    if(state.data.length === 0)
    {
      return;
    }
    state.data.pop();
    this.setState(state);
  }

  getAllStates() {
    let { data } = this.state;
    let output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      try {
        let item = data[i];
        output.push(JSON.parse(item));
      } catch (err) {
        alert("One or more items are not valid JSON");
        return;
      }
    }

    //Do some stuff with output
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map((val, ind) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <br />
              <textarea onChange={e => this.onChange(e, ind)} value={val} />
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <br />
        <button onClick={this.addField}>Add Field</button>
        <button onClick={this.removeField}>Remove Field</button>
        <button onClick={this.getAllStates}>Save JSON</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I click run code snippet I got this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `

Comment: Because react is not enabled in the snippet. Try copying an pasting in sandbox

Comment: you don't do JSON.stringify in render how would the textarea show the json?

Comment: The entire thing is just treated as a string until it's time to submit. This bypasses errors caused by the component trying to stringify and parse with every key stroke.

Comment: I see what you did there, you did not load the json that's why it's easy. Try to load existing json and do edit, I don't have problem doing add.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172558/discussion-between-eddie-del-rio-and-melissa92).